# Texstudio focusses by default on the internal pdf viewer (windowed) when I call build and show. How can I change this?

Tags: pdf, texstudio, viewers

I would like to stay focussed on the editor when pressing F5 (build and show). Is this possible? My current command is `txs:///view-pdf-internal --windowed`.
Do I need to pass a new flag to the pdf viewer or change something inside texstudio?
I am using Ubuntu 20.04
TeXstudio 2.12.22 (Build: 2.12.22+debian-1build1)
Using Qt-Version 5.12.8,
compiled with Qt 5.12.5 R

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is to add  `--no-focus` to the field 'Default Viewer' in your TeXstudio settings

[image]

Edit: I tested this in a newer version (3.0.4) of TeXstudio only

Comment: Perfect thank you a lot!